# =My laptop touchpad is not working after changing the keyboard

Tags: keyboard, mouse, hardware-failure, touchpad

Is this the reason why my mousepad is not working ? After giving it to someone to change my keyboard he damaged the connector.

Image link below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/an6Os.jpg

Comment: Is the plastic around the connector broken? It looks like it. That could prevent those unsupported contacts from making a good connection.

Comment: Or somebody ham-fisted enough to break the socket on a simple ribbon cable could have managed to jog anything else loose too…

Comment: Take it back and tell him to fix it properly